# Highlighting duplicate content from user input in a Word document written in Hebrew

Tags: vba, windows, ms-word, hebrew

I am trying to highlight duplicate content based on user input, in dark red (color doesn't matter).

I ran the code in the Word document, written in Hebrew, and it appeared to fail. I ran it with English text and it worked. Unfortunately the task is for the code to function in Hebrew not English.

When the code appears, it shows *'?????? ???'* in the *UserInput* value when user inputs Hebrew text during debugging.

It seems the character type is not supported, how can I make the character type support the Hebrew text? Is it a different Unicode?

```vb
Sub HighlightDupl()

    Dim UserInput As String
    Dim SentArray() As String
    Dim n As Long, i As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    UserInput = InputBox("הדבק משפט לבדיקת כפילויות -- Paste sentence to check for duplicates", "הַצהָרָה -- Statement")
    ' Check if input is empty, if yes - quit program
    If UserInput Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    TargetList = Array(UserInput)

    For i = 0 To UBound(TargetList)

        Set range = ActiveDocument.range

        With range.Find
            .Text = TargetList(i)
            .Format = True
            .MatchCase = True
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False

            Do While .Execute(Forward:=True) = True
                range.HighlightColorIndex = wdDarkRed
            Loop

        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

The Hebrew in the code is also not read properly so I removed it from the code I ran, I left it there now as a reference for Hebrew text.

Recently when trying to work on the program again, the code gave a few runtime errors like *Type Mismatch*. Was there an update in the last few weeks that suddenly made my code error?

I changed the *UserInput* variable to a *Variant* type after and there was some progress but the code didn't function as intended. The content will be mostly Hebrew text but there could be numbers as well.

Something else I've tried is to change the input language and proofing language to Hebrew. The document is mixed with both English and Hebrew. Should I have all English removed first for this to work?

Comment: MS Word itself should be unicode. However, a simple test on my local install shows that the InputBox function is not unicode--I tried inserting chinese characters into the input and then display the results using MsgBox and got '???????' which is a classic sign of failure to convert from unicode to local code page. Googling old answers indicates that InputBox is not unicode so that you'll have to roll your own replacement for InputBox or find a replacement. You could try to set the "ANSI" code page of the system to Hebrew (but I'd be surprised if it isn't already that)

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson Thanks for your input (no pun intended). It does appear that the _InputBox_ does not accept special characters. I am going to look for an alternative to that, maybe a user form? I am going to manually do this with the Find/Replace feature if no VBA code works. I am trying to automate the task, it is a large document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a general level, you could use a *wildcard* Find/Replace, where:

```
Find = (<*>) \1
Replace = ^&
```

and you set the Highlight colour to whatever you prefer. No macros needed.

The above *wildcard* Find/Replace will find any duplicate pair of words (Hebrew or otherwise) separated by a space, without the need to nominate the words concerned.

To be able to use Unicode (e.g. Hebrew) input via a VBA InputBox, you need to do two things:

1. in the Windows Control Panel, choose Region>Administrative>Change System Local> Current system locale: and set the native language you want to use. Note that this only directly affects programs that don't support Unicode. You will need to restart Windows for this change to take effect.
2. In VBA Editor, choose Tools>Options>Editor Format>Font and select, say, Courier New (or any other font that supports Unicode).

Comment: This answers my question! After following the 2 steps described, the VBA InputBox Function understood the Hebrew characters. Your other alternative is also helpful.